# Angular2: Subscription on Observable wont assign response value

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services

I am trying to find an `ID` from a table in my databse by querying my backend with a custom query. However, when I am sending a `GET Method` with my Service and `subscribing` to the `Observable`, it `won't assign` the response (which is only a number), to my `property` of the service class. 
Here my code:

```
    rentedCarId:string;


  getId(id:number): void {
    let url = this.baseUrl+"/search/findRentedCar?customer="+sessionStorage.getItem("customerID")+"&car="+id;

    console.log("Input id: " + id);

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

    this
      .http
      .get(url, {headers})
      .map(resp => resp.text())
      .subscribe(
        (id) => {
            console.log(id); //This will print out the number!
            this.rentedCarId = id; //This won't work! => undefined
        },
        (err) => {
      console.error('Error while searching for rentedCar ID!', err);
    });

    }




  deleteRentedCarEntry(id:number){
      this.getId(id);
      console.log("ID of Row in RentedCars table (response): " + this.rentedCarId); //will be undefined!
  }
```

The method `deleteRentedCarEntry()` is executed from my other component.
If I execute it at the start of the application, the `log` in the `deleteRentedCarEntry()` returns `undefined` for the `rentedCarId` property!
The `console.log` in the `subscribe` method however, logs the correct value, even at the first time! Why does it not assign the `id` value from the response after the first time but only at the second time?

Comment: You need to return the observable in getId, and when you call it in deleteRentedCarEntry subscribe to that observable then print it out.

Comment: @Steveadoo That would have the same effect as it is now. The only thing which would change, is that I would subscribe in the other method and thats it! By the way it does not work either!

Comment: No, right now you're immediately trying to log the rentedCarId, before the http request ever comes back. `this.rentedCarId = id;` is being called after       `console.log("ID of Row in RentedCars table (response): " + this.rentedCarId); //will be undefined!`

Comment: @AJT_82 the `.text()` method returns the body as a string, presuming `.toString()` can be called on the body. By the way, I have already tried `.json()`, same result.

Comment: @Steveadoo Yes I know. So I should instead subscribe to it in the other method? If I am trying to subscribe in the `deleteRentedCarEntry()` to it, the same effect occurs. It will return undefined for the property `rentedCarId` even though the `Observable` was already returned and afterwards subscribed to!

Comment: Well why do you have to set rentedCarId at all,if you're calling getId all the time? Can't you just subscribe to the observable returned by getId and use the id returned there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a do to set the rentedCarId.

```
  getId(id:number): Observable<any> {
    let url = this.baseUrl+"/search/findRentedCar?customer="+sessionStorage.getItem("customerID")+"&car="+id;

    console.log("Input id: " + id);

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

    return this
      .http
      .get(url, {headers})
      .map(resp => resp.text())
      .do(id => this.rentedCardId = id);
    }

  deleteRentedCarEntry(id:number){
      this.getId(id).subscribe((rentedCarId) => {
          console.log("ID of Row in RentedCars table (response): " + this.rentedCarId); //will be undefined!
      });
  }
```

Comment: Of course I need it! The `log` of the `rentedCarId` property in the `deleteRentedCarEntry` was for debugging purposes. That's also whats my question about! I want to save the value from the returned `Observable` and not only `log` it to the console..

Comment: Ok, but you were debugging incorrectly. It was coming out as undefined because you were executing it right away, instead of waiting for the observable to complete. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Oh ok I see! So when using `Observables` you can `.subscribe()` to them, but in the `subscribe()` method it won't store the data in a property if it hasn't finished loading yet...and the `do()` method is waiting until it has returned? Thank you for your solution, its very good!

Comment: Not exactly. You should look up some tutorials on rxjs, and async javascript. You're welcome though!

Comment: I will do that for sure! Thank you!